# WCF Session aborting on exception

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

After adding **IErrorHandler** in service I want to abort session when Service throwing not **FaultException**.

```
public bool HandleError(Exception error) { 
    return error.GetType() == typeof(FaultException); 
}
```

This works fine when running in local. The client's InnerChannel state get Faulted. 
But after publishing the service, client not getting faulted state, making the UI waiting for response.

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing not FaultException" what kind of exception can also occur?

Comment: I have a method which throws a FaultException with custom messages that returns to client, such as validation errors. But I need to abort the session when the exception not handled. For example if NullReferenceException occured the service must log the exception and abort the session.

Comment: So you are stopping receiving `NullReferenceException` (and other not inherited from `FaultException`) exceptions when you run service on another workstation? Do you run it in IIS?

Comment: Yes the service is running with IIS.
Remote debugging shows that the HandleError returns false. But the problem is that session remains.